# React Native app crashes without any error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The app will build successfully in both development and production but when I run expo start --dev-client my app crashes, I try to resolved last two days but not fix it. I am stuck please help me out. Why my app crash??

I  check adb logcat but nothing found any error. If you have any idea?
[Here is my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0MEZ.png)

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

Comment: Thanks, @HarshitMadhav but it's not working still when I run my app crash. How to fix it?

Comment: please update the question with what you tried and what is the exact behaviour for the error?

Comment: My problem is React native Android app crashes immediately after run it give runtime exception

Comment: might be related to hermes please disable it and then try to re run

Comment: enableHermes:false in app/build.gradle Already disabled

Comment: sorry like this then I wont be able to help as it is out of scope now will have to figure it out. Either it could be flipper issue or something else

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0MEZ.png     This error show in logcat error mode when my app crash.